# python pandas dataframe sort in descending order

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to sort kst column in descending order.

```
df.sort_values(by=['kst'], ascending=False)
```

Even though I put the above code, it doesn't works and result is following.

```
           kst            test  test
 0    2018-07-08 10:00    2a    8
 1    2018-07-08 09:30    2e    6
 2    2018-07-08 09:00    32    3
 3    2018-07-08 08:30    r2    2
 4    2018-07-08 08:00    f2    4
 5    2018-07-08 07:30    w2    6
 6    2018-07-08 07:00    s2    7
 7    2018-07-08 06:30    e2    5
 8    2018-07-08 06:00    e2    2
```

How can I sort kst column in descending order?

Comment: Looks sorted to me...

Comment: `df=df.sort_values(by=['kst'], ascending=False)` assign it back

Answer (score 1):

The kst column is already sorted based on time in that column...what else do u want to sort based on kst ? if u want to sort other columns ,then i suggest u to specify the exact column name you want to sort like example , df.sort_values(by=['test'], ascending=False).

Comment: As you said, the kst column is already sorted in ascending order. But I'd like to sort kst column in descending orde NOT ascending order. Your suggested code doesn't woks. It means kst colume is still ascending order.

Comment: The sort of kst column already seem to be in descending order (highest time first and then reducing to lowest time). What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

There is a switch for that: `inplace= True`, see the [manual](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)